# Create a CI/CD pipeline in GitLab to create an executable

Tags: python, gitlab, pyinstaller, gitlab-ci, executable

I have a Python project in GitLab and I want to create a pipeline which creates a new executable using PyInstaller every time changes are pushed to the project.

How can I achieve this? Using YAML script?

Comment: Have you read [the docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/quick_start/)?